# How to order a grouped result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating an Rails 3.2.14 app.
In this app I got a model called Timereport. In the model I got a class method
that I am using to generate statistics.

```
def self.stats_time_spent(params)
 data = group("date(created_at)")
 data = data.where("backend_user_id = ?", params[:backend_user_id])
 data = data.where("created_at >= ?", params[:date_from])
 data = data.where("created_at <= ?", params[:date_to])
 data = data.select("date (created_at) as timecreated, sum(total_time) as timetotal")
 data
end
```

This function works but it outputs data in a random fashion. The dates are not sorted.
I tried to add .order("created_at desc") but then I get this error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "timereports.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...user_id = '1') GROUP BY date(created_at) ORDER BY created_at...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, date(created_at) AS date_created_at FROM "timereports"  WHERE
```

I got two questions. Is this a good way of aggregating the data and how do I order the output?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should order by `date(created_at)`